# Calculate the dependency standard deviation in R

Tags: r, statistics, calculated-columns, standard-deviation, crowdsourcing

I want to calculate the standard deviation in R. But the standard function "sd(x)" is not the function that I need. I'm looking for a function to calculate the sd(x, in dependency of another variable in my dataframe). So that I can add a new column with the sd by the dependency variable (image).
Like this:

```
image   answer    sd
a       1         0,70
a       2         0,70
b       2         2,12
b       5         2,12
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `ave` is perfect for this.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
image   answer    sd
a       1         0,70
a       2         0,70
b       2         2,12
b       5         2,12
", header = TRUE, dec = ",")

ave(dat$answer, dat$image, FUN = sd)
#[1] 0.7071068 0.7071068 2.1213203 2.1213203
```

**EDIT.**
Following the dialog with Henry in the comments, I have decided to edit the answer. Fortunately so, since that in the mean time I realized that the original dataset uses the comma as a decimal point.
So, first change, to include argument `dec = ","` in the `read.table` above.
Second change, to show a complete solution with column `sd` created by the `ave` instruction.

```
dat2 <- dat[-3]  # start with the OP's data without the 3rd column
dat2$sd <- ave(dat2$answer, dat2$image, FUN = sd)
dat2
#  image answer        sd
#1     a      1 0.7071068
#2     a      2 0.7071068
#3     b      2 2.1213203
#4     b      5 2.1213203
```

Comment: +1 though perhaps you could leave the `sd` column out of the input and then insert the calculations into the table with something like `dat$sd <- ave(dat$answer, dat$image, FUN = sd)` and then print the result

Comment: @Henry You're right, but I used the data example as the OP posted it.

Comment: I had thought that that was the desired output rather than the input.  It doesn't matter either way

Comment: Thank's for your comments. Your solutions are perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want the standard deviation of the answer for each image. You can group your df by image then use sd, which will calculate separetly for each group using dplyr.

```
df <- data.frame(image = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
                 answer = c(1, 2, 2, 5))

library(dplyr)    
df %>%
        group_by(image) %>%
        mutate(sd = sd(answer))
```